# PrimeFaces "tabChange" event with dynamic number of tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to get title of currently active tab inside my TabView. TabView is constructed with dynamic number of tabs with listener attached to "tabChanged":

```
<p:tabView value="#{bean.list}" var="listItem">
  <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{listenerBean.onChange}" />
  <p:tab title="#{listItem.stringProperty}">
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

The problem is that TabChangeEvent object received by onChange(TabChangeEvent event) always contains first tab instead of the active one.

```
public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    event.getTab().getTitle(); //allways returns title of first tab
}
```

This behavior is only true for dynamic number of tabs in TabView if I define each tab explicitly, TabChangeEvent works fine.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

I use PrimeFaces 3.5 with JSF2.1 and Servlets 2.5

Comment: Where did you get this character `”`? It is not a double quote character.

Comment: Try a more recent version

Comment: Tiny, the ” character is just added in stackOvf editor, so it's not the reason.  Kukeltje, I would like to, but can't change version it's project specific.

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example worked for my like a charm by printing the title of the tab to activate every time I click on it:

## page.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <f:view>
        <h:head/>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:tabView value="#{bean.items}"
                           var="item">
                    <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                            listener="#{bean.printTitle}"
                            update="@form"/>
                    <p:tab title="#{item}">
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

## Bean.java

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.primefaces.event.TabChangeEvent;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private final List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Hello", "This", "Is", "TabView");

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void printTitle(TabChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("title = [" + event.getTab().getTitle() + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: with what version? 3.5 like the OP?

Comment: So I checked your code and had no luck. With PF3.5, JSF2.1, Servlet2.5 on WebLogic 10.3.6 I get the same "title=[Hello]" on every tab click. With PF4.0 I get "title=[]" with every click. Also tried PF4.0, JSF2.2 and Servlet3 on  Tomcat8 the result is the same: "title = []". Could you describe your setup on which this code works?

Comment: Even 4.0 is 'old'  try newer